# Draw an exclusion plot using a set of inequalities(make a loglogregionplot)

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, logarithmic-scale

```
logLogRegionPlot[rplot_] := 
 Module[{pts, pgon},
  pts = Cases[Normal@rplot, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity];
  pgon = {EdgeForm[], 
          Directive[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
          AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Opacity[0.3]], 
          Cases[Normal@rplot, Polygon[_], Infinity]};
  ListLogLogPlot[
    pts,
    Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
    PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1,
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1],
    Epilog -> (pgon /. {x_, y_?NumericQ} :> Log@{x, y})
  ]
 ]

logLogRegionPlot@
  RegionPlot[
     {y > 8*(10^-10) (x)^(1/2)*HeavisideTheta[(x)^(-1) - (y)] &&
      x > 6*(10^4) && x < 6*(10^10) && 
      y < (8*(10^-10))^-1 x^(-5/2)*HeavisideTheta[-(x)^(-1) + (y)] && 
      y > 0.6*x^(-3/2)}, 
     {x, 10^2, 10^6}, {y, 10^-6, 10^-2}, 
     PlotPoints -> 100
  ]
```

How can I produce a log region plot satisfying those inequalities?

I have tried to produce it with the above code. An exclusion region is coming, but I need a large plot range (xaxis€[10^2,10^14], yaxis€[10^-16,10^0]) for which it is giving a wrong plot.

This was already asked in Wolfram community
[Wolfram community asked question][1]

[1]: [https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2116321?p_p_auth=mXPP5Nq0![My](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2116321?p_p_auth=mXPP5Nq0!%5BMy) plot in MMA 12.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwReG.png)

Comment: Have you noticed that your `RegionPlot` expression returns an empty plot? The problem does not seem to be in `logLogRegionPlot`, at least not yet. First you will need to make `RegionPlot` work. I don't understand what region you are trying to plot. Can you describe it mathematically or in words perhaps?

Comment: If you reduce the plot range(say, x->(10^2,10^4),y->(10^-14,10^-9)) in the above code then it will give a plot but it is giving an empty plot for this large plot range what I needed

Comment: I tried, but I still cannot get a plot, even with the ranges you mentioned. I am on MMA 12.0.0 on Win10-64. Could you try to run just the RegionPlot code you posted on a clean kernel, just to make sure that you can reproduce it? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @MarcoB now I have added a screenshot of my notebook

Comment: Your code is difference from  the picture . Please  post  your  new code .

Comment: Sorry for creating the confusion, now I have corrected it

Comment: `{x, 100, 600000}, {y, 0, 0.0015}` ,in this range, the region is bigger.

Comment: try `loglogRP = Show[# /. GraphicsComplex[c_, p___] :> GraphicsComplex[Log[c], p], 
   PlotRange -> All] &`?

Comment: or ``loglogRP =  Show[# /. GraphicsComplex[c_, p___] :> GraphicsComplex[Log[c], p], 
    PlotRange -> All,    FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Log"], 
       Charting`ScaledFrameTicks["Log"]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks["Log"], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks["Log"]}}] &;``

Comment: @kglr now also the plot is coming from your trick but the problem remains the same for a large plot range it is returning an empty plot

Comment: Is their any other way of plotting those inequalities than region plotting since the main issue here is for region plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of the variables does the job.

```
RegionPlot[({y > 8*(10^-10) (x)^(1/2)*HeavisideTheta[(x)^(-1) - (y)] &&
  x > 6*(10^4) && x < 6*(10^10) && 
 y < (8*(10^-10))^-1 x^(-5/2)*HeavisideTheta[-(x)^(-1) + (y)] && 
 y > 0.6*x^(-3/2)}) /. {x -> Exp[s], y -> Exp[t]}, {s, Log[10^2], Log[10^6]}, {t, Log[10^-6], Log[10^-2]}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this approach is somehow wrong, since actually the region should be placed near x€{10^3,10^6}

Comment: @JohnWick: I leave the change of the ticks on your own.

Comment: I have tried this approach for my desired plot range but the region seems misplaced

Comment: @JohnWick: What is your "desired plot range"?

Comment: The plot screen shot is attached in the question, I just asking to adjust my plot range x(10^2,10^14),y(10^-15,10^0)

Comment: @JohnWick: Sorry, don't understand you. The command `RegionPlot[({y > 8*(10^-10) (x)^(1/2)*HeavisideTheta[(x)^(-1) - (y)] &&
  x > 6*(10^4) && x < 6*(10^10) && 
 y < (8*(10^-10))^-1 x^(-5/2)*HeavisideTheta[-(x)^(-1) + (y)] && 
 y > 0.6*x^(-3/2)}) /. {x -> Exp[s], y -> Exp[t]}, {s, Log[10^2], Log[10^14]}, {t, Log[10^-15], Log[10^0]}, PlotPoints -> 50]` works.

Comment: The region from your code is different than the region one can get from loglogregionplot .please see the attactched link

Comment: @JohnWick: Therefore, at least one of these plots is not correct. I don't see any mistake in my code: the change of the variables, no more and no less.